# Regular expression or complete javaScript to validate Salary (a 'Double' number)?

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate salary text field with java script in my html page having syntax like
`Max six digits, a dot, max two digits after dot` and it can be done in two ways:

1) I make user only enter integer values and `append a dot and two zeros at the end` by some `javaScript code`.

2) Check the entry given by user at time of `formValidation` with a `regex` that can pass the right syntax as i described above...

Which will be the simpler one? And how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

> Max six digits, a dot, max two digits after dot

```
/^\d{1,6}(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

It actually means between 1 and six digits, followed by optionally a dot and a max of two digits.

If you want to require the dot, then use

```
/^\d{1,6}\.\d{0,2}$/
```

If you want to allow commas, e.g. `150,000`, then try replacing `\d{1,6}` with

```
\d{1,3}(?:,?\d{3})?
```

Comment: It's worth remembering that non-US nations may use a comma as a decimal separator instead of a period. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu-Arabic_numeral_system

Comment: @mblase75, Good point.  I'm just trying to answer the question as asked.  Non-US nations may also break runs of digits into myriads of 2 or 4 digits instead of the 3 which is standard in the US.

Comment: true, my comment should have been attached to the OP instead of your answer.

Comment: @mblase75, no worries.  People sometimes link directly to answers, so it's good if caveats appear with answers so that people don't construe them as applying too broadly when removed from the context of the question.